# What does "it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 22" indicate?

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked everywhere for the meaning of errno 22 and have failed to find any information on it:

> 2020-06-24 11:39:09.483111-0600 MyApp[1773:478284] Foundation called mkdir("/private/var/mobile/Library/LiveFiles/com.apple.filesystems.userfsd/MyUSB//My_Files/myiphone/IMG_2302.JPG.sb-db06fe8e-O0frER"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 22.
> End copy of photo data = 673587 bytes of IMG_2302.JPG

I see this when looping though an array of PHAssets and copying them to an external drive.  All works fine for the first ~2000 photos, then suddenly all photos after this report this errno 22.

I've tried catching more details on this error with try/catch but nothing ever is caught.  So, I assume it is coming from somewhere in Foundation or something?

Memory usage stays low pretty consistent at around 40MB.

What does errno 22 indicate the issue as being?

The relevant part of the loop where I am copying is as follows.  Same issue is seen whether using data.write or Filemanager.default.createfile:

```
_ = autoreleasepool {
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(
                for: mediaFile,
                options: options) { (data, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
                    
                    if data != nil {
                        self.imgData = data!
                    }
            }
        }
        
        let toFileNameURL = destinationPathURL.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)
            
        let completed = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: toFileNameURL.path, contents: imgData, attributes: nil)
        print("copy worked?  \(completed)")
        //try self.imgData.write(to: toFileNameURL, options: .atomic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself has a little value for you. It's coming from `sys/errno.h`, deep in Foundation woods. It's a standard C file, you can find many copies of it online (e.g. [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.31.3/bsd/sys/errno.h.auto.html)). Your particular error looks like this:

```
#define EINVAL      22      /* Invalid argument */
```

The error is possibly coming from [dirhelper](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.1.1/darwin/_dirhelper.c), but even that doesn't help you much.

So instead look what is causing it. Big clue is that it only happens after 2000 files. OOM, space on USB, or exceeding some other limits are top suspects.

Second question is why is it complaining about `mkdir`, while you copy files?

Comment: Thanks for the response and info @Kiril.  Good question about why it is complaining about mkdir.  I like your suggestions about OOM, space on USB, etc as well.  I'll dig into it and will also accept answer as you answered what errno 22 meant.

Comment: After further analysis, it looks like it was a hardware issue with USB drive.  Using another drive does not have this issue.  I did not follow troubleshooting 101 here apparently.  :-)  The link @Kirik provided to the sys/errno.h file was very helpful.